# Angular CLI 6. Can't use custom library components in child modules of app.module

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I have created several custom libraries, which I then installed into another project. All of the library components exported by public_api are usable inside app.module. However in a child module (account.module) none of the components are detected. I have tried placing all the libraries into 'exports' and a few other things, but I can't get the components I need exposed in a module below app.module.

The following example is z-navigation-lib, a custom library with one component:

public_api:

```
export * from './lib/z-navigation-lib.service';
export * from './lib/z-navigation-lib.component';
export * from './lib/z-navigation-lib.module';
```

z-navigation-lib.module:

```
@NgModule({


imports: [
    CommonModule, RouterModule, HttpClientModule, OverlayPanelModule, ZServicesLibModule,
    InlineSVGModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [ZNavigationLibComponent, NavbarSideComponent, NavbarTopComponent, NavbarMenuComponent, NavbarMenuItem, UserControls, AlarmsOverlayComponent, TasksOverlayComponent],
  providers: [ModuleMenuService, NavigationMenuService, ZNavigationLibService],
  exports: [ZNavigationLibComponent]
})
export class ZNavigationLibModule { }
```

The `app-routing.component.ts` file of the project importing z-navigation-lib:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
@NgModule({
  imports:
    [
      RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/pages/account/account.module#AccountModule' }
      ])
    ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

The `app.module.ts` of the project importing z-navigation-lib:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    ZNavigationLibModule,
    AccountModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ZNavigationLibModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, the errors that I get when I attempt to build --prod the app:

```
ERROR in : Can't bind to 'menuParams' since it isn't a known property of 'z-navigation'.
1. If 'z-navigation' is an Angular component and it has 'menuParams' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'z-navigation' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("<z-navigation [ERROR ->][menuParams]="menuParams"></z-navigation>
<z-search>
  <z-custom label="Account Short Code">
")
: 'z-navigation' is not a known element:
```

Keep in mind that z-navigation works fine in app.module. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi!
Did you solved this?
I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @AndriiRomanchak, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an answer for @Andrii Romanchak.

I couldn't make the project work the way I wanted it in the question. My workaround was to make a Shared module which imported and exported ZNavigationLibModule. I then added the Shared module to AppModules imports (nothing in exports). Then import SharedModule into any module which is a child of AppModule.

Quick note: If you have any services in those libraries, this method might stop your services from being singletons. To counter this, I made a .forRoot() method for the ZServicesLibModule, and avoided importing it into SharedModule.

This is my AppModule at the moment. You can see what I did with Shared Module and ZServicesLibModule (since it **needs** to give me singleton services):

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    ZServicesLibModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [GlobalAccessControlService],
  exports: [ZServicesLibModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

In any child module of AppModule, just import the library you need as a singleton, the normal way, in my case like this:

```
import { ZServicesLibModule } from 'z-services-lib';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ZServicesLibModule, ...]
})
```